# Dúvida sobre código em C

Tags: c

Olá. Estou com dúvidas sobre este código.

No "case 1", ao executar, me aparece isto:

[image]

O problema é que nenhum dos descontos é aplicado. Já tentei outras formas de montar esta operação, mas todas resultam em erro.

Já no "case 2", queria saber se existe uma forma de, " if (c==987)" virar " if (c==0987)", sem que ocorra erros referentes à base octal. E, de preferência, tem que ser da forma como está no código, já que foi a forma como o professor nos instruiu a fazer, inicialmente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

int quant, questoes,codigo;
float preco, valor, calculo, desconto, salario, valor1, valor2, valor3;
char nome_produto;

puts("----- RESOLUÇÃO DE PROBLEMAS -----");
puts("Digite o número da questão desejada:\n1 - Desconto em Produtos\n2 - Códigos de Produtos \n3 - Rejuste de Salário \n4 - Maior valor \n5 - Soma de Valores ");
scanf("%d",&questoes);

       switch(questoes){
                        case 1:
                                system("cls");
                                puts("Digite o nome do produto");
                                scanf(" %[^\n]c ",&nome_produto);
                                puts ("Digite a quantidade adquirida");
                                scanf ("%i",&quant);
                                puts ("Digite o preço do produto");
                                scanf ("%f",&preco);
                                if ("quant<=10") {
                                                  calculo = preco * quant;
                                                  printf ("Seu produto não pode obter desconto. O preço total é de: %.2f",calculo);
                                              }
                                else if ("quant<=20") {
                                                  desconto = preco * quant * 10/100;
                                                  calculo=preco*quant-desconto;
                                                  printf ("Seu produto obteu um desconto de 10%. O preço total é de: %.2f",calculo);
                                  }
                                else if ("quant<=50") {
                                                  desconto = preco * quant * 20/100;
                                                  calculo = preco * quant - desconto;
                                                  printf ("Seu produto obteu um desconto de 20%. O preço total é de: %.2f",calculo);
                                  }
                                else if ("quant>50") {
                                                  desconto = preco * quant * 25/100;
                                                  calculo = preco * quant - desconto;
                                                  printf ("Seu produto obteu um desconto de 25%. O preço total é de: %.2f",calculo);
                                  }
                        break;

                        case 2:
                                system("cls");
                                puts("Digite o código do produto");
                                scanf("%i",&codigo);
                                puts("Digite a quantidade adquirida");
                                scanf("%i",&quant);
                                if (codigo==1001) {
                                    calculo=quant*5.32;
                                    printf("O valor total é %.2f",calculo);
                                }
                                if (codigo==1324) {
                                    calculo=quant*6.45;
                                    printf("O valor total é %.2f",calculo);
                                }
                                if (codigo==6548) {
                                    calculo=quant*2.37;
                                    printf("O valor total é %.2f",calculo);
                                }
                                if (codigo==987) {
                                    calculo=quant*5.32;
                                    printf("O valor total é %.2f",calculo);
                                }
                                if (codigo==7623) {
                                    calculo=quant*6.45;
                                    printf("O valor total é %.2f",calculo);
                                }
                                else
                                    puts("Código Inválido");
                        break;

                        case 3:
                                system("cls");
                                puts("Digite o código funcional");
                                scanf("%i",&codigo);
                                puts("Digite o salário atual do funcionário");
                                scanf("%f",&salario);
                                if (codigo==01) {
                                    calculo=salario*1.15;
                                    printf("O salário atual, após o reajute de 15 por cento é de: %.2f. Seu cargo é de operador.",calculo);
                                }
                                if (codigo==02) {
                                    calculo=salario*1.1;
                                    printf("O salário atual, após o reajute de 10 por cento é de: %.2f. Seu cargo é de supervisor.",calculo);
                                }
                                if (codigo==03) {
                                    calculo=salario*1.05;
                                    printf("O salário atual, após o reajute de 5 por cento é de: %.2f. Seu cargo é de gerente.",calculo);
                                }
                                if (codigo==04) {
                                    printf("O salário atual é de: %.2f. Seu cargo é de diretor.",salario);
                                }
                                else
                                    puts("Código Inválido");

                        break;

                        case 4:
                              system("cls");
                              puts("Entre com o primeiro valor");
                              scanf("%f",&valor1);
                              puts("Entre com o segundo valor");
                              scanf("%f",&valor2);
                              puts("Entre com o terceiro valor");
                              scanf("%f",&valor3);
                              if (valor1>valor2, valor1>valor3) {
                                puts("O primeiro valor é maior");
                              }
                              else if (valor2>valor1, valor2>valor3) {
                                puts("O segundo valor é maior");
                              }
                              else if (valor3>valor1, valor3>valor2) {
                                puts("O terceiro valor é maior");
                              }
                              else
                                puts("Os valores são iguais");
                        break;

                        case 5:
                              system("cls");
                              puts("Entre com o primeiro valor");
                              scanf("%f",&valor1);
                              puts("Entre com o segundo valor");
                              scanf("%f",&valor2);
                              puts("Entre com o terceiro valor");
                              scanf("%f",&valor3);
                              if (valor1>valor3, valor2>valor3) {
                                calculo=valor1+valor2;
                                printf("%.0f + %.0f = %.0f",valor1,valor2,calculo);
                              }
                              else if (valor1>valor2, valor3>valor2) {
                                calculo=valor1+valor3;
                                printf("%.0f + %.0f = %.0f",valor1,valor3,calculo);
                              }
                              else if (valor3>valor1, valor2>valor1) {
                                calculo=valor2+valor3;
                                printf("%.0f + %.0f = %.0f",valor2,valor3,calculo);
                              }
                              else
                                puts("Os valores são iguais");
                        break;

                        default:
                                puts ("Opção Inválida");
                        }

}
```

Para deixar mais claro, tudo isso faz parte de questões acadêmicas. Estou aprendendo agora. Deixarei o comando correspondente ao case 1 abaixo:

> Case 1

1. Faça um programa que leia o nome de um produto, o preço e a quantidade comprada. Escreva o nome do produto comprado e o valor total a ser pago, considerando que são oferecidos descontos pelo número de unidades compradas, segundo dados abaixo:

   - Até 10 unidades - valor total
   - De 11 a 20 unidades - 10% de desconto
   - De 21 a 50 unidades - 20% de desconto
   - Acima de 50 unidades - 25% de desconto

Comment: `%d, &c `? Você está jogando codificação binária de um decimal de (possivelmente) 4 bytes em um endereço interpretado como ponto flutuante IEEE de 4 bytes, essa leitura não vai retornar um resultado como confiável

Comment: Olá. Adicionei os comandos das questões. Espero que esteja de melhor entendimento agora.

Answer (score 0):

Caso 1

Voce tem que printar na tela a mensagem para digitar nome.
Depois usar o scanf para receber o resultado.
Depois printar na tela a mensagem para digitar preço.
Depois usar o scanf para receber o resultado.

Caso 2

Primeira coisa que você deve fazer que vai te ajudar e ajudar os outros a ler seu código é colocar nomes compreensíveis em suas variáveis. Nomes como a,x,y,z não ajudam em nada entender o que esta acontecendo. Coloque nomes como "produto", "quantidade", "preco".

Bom, no caso dois eu não vou resolver para você porque é uma questão academica, mas vou te dar os passos para resolver a questão:

1- Peça pro usuario digitar o código do produto e receba o valor
2- Peça para ele digitar a quantidade e receba o valor
3- Faça um switch para pegar o preco do produto que ele escolheu, apenas o preço. Não precisa colocar os IFS dentro do switch senão vai ficar repetindo código. Algo assim ó:

```
double preco;

switch(codigo) {

    case 1001:
        preco = 5.32;

E ASSIM POR DIANTE....
```

4- Depois disso crie a verificação da quantidade. Se ela for até dez pega a quantidade e multiplica pelo preço, se for de 11 a vinte faz quantidade vezes preco menos 20% e por aí vai.

Bom espero que consiga resolver mas é muito importante que você mesmo resolva porque vai te ajudar imensamente no futuro.

Comment: Olá. Bem, no que se refere ao caso 1, eu editei o post, já que agora o erro é diferente. Mas eu descobri o porque de não estar conseguindo inserir caracteres. Já o caso 2, eu consegui que funcionasse, mas continuo com o problema referente a base octal. Ah, e obrigada pela dica! Já modifiquei o código, realmente facilita a leitura.

Comment: Tira esse if else de dentro do switch e deixa ele apenas pra determinar  preço igual te mostrei na resposta.

Depois do switch faz o seu if apenas pra ver o desconto.

if(preco <= 10) {
    nao tem desconto
} else if (preco >10 && preco <= 20) {
    precoFinal = preco blablabla
}

Entendeu?

Comment: [Dessa](http://i.imgur.com/vaMqx4h.png) forma?

Comment: Isso e seu erro de octal é que ta iniciando uma variavel com 0 como primeiro numero e quando inicia ela com ela é tratada como numero de base 8. Remova o 0 da frente.

Comment: Pois é, era essa minha dúvida. O problema é que a atividade pede esse código. Acho que o melhor seria me informar com meu professor. De qualquer forma, obrigada.

Comment: Transforma seu código em uma string ou invés de um inteiro que resolve o problema

Answer (score 0):

Uma dica para você solucionar esse problema é determinar uma variavel para unidade e preco.

Exemplo:

```
float quantidade = 0;
float preco = 0;
```

Sendo assim,

Voce pega o codigo do produto, verifica  o preco do produto e incrementa esse valor na variavel preco, e incrementa 1 na variavel quantidade.

No final é só checar.